# gulp protractor - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:48107

Tags: selenium, gulp, protractor

```
vegan@vegan:~/xxx-yyy/gateway$ gulp protractor qa
[10:52:58] Using gulpfile ~/xxx-yyy/gateway/gulpfile.js
[10:52:58] Starting 'protractor'...
[10:52:58] Starting 'qa'...
[10:52:58] Finished 'qa' after 76 μs
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174
      callback(new Error(message));
               ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:48107
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:306:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1265:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
    at new Driver (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:810:36)
    at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:68:16)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:186:37)
    at /home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:276:21
    at _fulfilled (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
[10:52:58] gulp-notify: [JHipster Gulp Build] Error: protractor exited with code 1
[10:52:58] Finished 'protractor' after 641 ms
[10:52:58] E2E Tests failed
```

i get this error when i run **gulp protractor qa**

[image]

it says

```
       at new Driver (/home/vegan/xxx-yyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:810:36)
```

it opens a chrome browser when i run but it stays at there browser.

the path is

/home/vegan/xxx/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver

i do

webdriver-manager update but it doesnot work

Why does this happen? I cant find a way for months.

```
vegan@vegan:~/xxx-yyyy/gateway$ webdriver-manager update
/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/logger.js:66
    info(...msgs) {
         ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/index.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```